# Consume Post method Rest + SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, rest

I have been searching all morning and i think i'm missing something .
i have a Spring boot controller with a method to save a client.
this is the method :

```
// ajouter un client
@RequestMapping(value="/AjoutClient/{clientData}", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String AjoutClient(@PathVariable String clientData) {

    Client c = new Client();
    c.setNomClient(clientData.split(";")[0]);
    c.setPrenomClient(clientData.split(";")[1]);
    c.setAdresseClient(clientData.split(";")[2]);
    c.setTelClient(clientData.split(";")[3]);
    c.setEmailClient(clientData.split(";")[4]);
    c.setCinClient(clientData.split(";")[5]);

    client.save(c);
    return "test";
}
```

i want to consume this method from another application with this method :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/ajoutClient", method=RequestMethod.POST)
 public void ajout(@RequestParam("nom") String nom,@RequestParam("prenom") String prenom,@RequestParam("adr") String adr,@RequestParam("tel") String tel,@RequestParam("mail") String mail,@RequestParam("cin") String cin) {

    String ClientData=nom+";"+prenom+";"+adr+";"+tel+";"+mail+";"+cin;

     RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

     HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(new String(ClientData));
     ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate
       .exchange("http://localhost:9093/AjoutClient/"+ClientData, HttpMethod.POST, request, String.class);

     assertThat(response.getStatusCode(), is(HttpStatus.CREATED));

  }
```

** explication : i get the values from a form and construct a string with those values, then try to send that string to my clientController.
PS: i can't send client object, i have to send the values one by one then create the client object in the clientController.
i'm feeling pretty lost because i can see that something is wrong but i don't know what is it.

Comment: What is the question/problem? Why don't you use a standard way of posting data, i.e. an url-encoded body, or JSON?

Comment: standard way ? how ? the problem is that the code is not working there is a problem somwhere

Comment: an url-encoded body, or JSON. Telling "it doesn't work" really doesn't help. That's like going to a doctor and only telling him "I'm sick".

Comment: He has a point, more information would be necessary. Like the actual payload (body of your post request) and a response when you make the call

Comment: i'm sorry i didnt specify cos i really didnt know what's the problem . it's working now .. the problem was in the separator i'm using ; i changed it to & and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I would suggest you avoid using `@PathVariable` for passing the data like this.
You're already sending everything in the request body, so first step is to change:

```
public String AjoutClient(@PathVariable String clientData) {
```

to

```
public String AjoutClient(@RequestBody String clientData) {
```

and

```
restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:9093/AjoutClient/" + ClientData, HttpMethod.POST, request, String.class);
```

to just

```
restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:9093/AjoutClient", HttpMethod.POST, request, String.class);
```

Then if you're expecting `201` status then you have to return it:

```
public ResponseEntity<String> AjoutClient(@RequestBody String clientData) {
    ...
    return ResponseEntity.created(null).body("test");
}
```

**PS:** Please pay attention to what @JB Nizet mentioned, cause he has  a point here. Just research that keywords (google them) or read some tutorials e.g https://www.baeldung.com/java-url-encoding-decoding or https://www.baeldung.com/rest-template and you'll easily find out more about standard practices.

Comment: i checked it as an aswer because it really works but my problem was about the semicolon i'm using to seperate the parameters . thanks :D